# Can I use html button to send request to java class?

Tags: java, android, html, cordova, android-studio

I want know that can I use html and javascript to make a template and export it as a android project(with phonegap)then use that into android studio for send request from html button to java class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that. Instead better create a phonegap project for android and create a template in it. Then you could import the project and make rest/ajax calls to the java services using button or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

try to using in this manner

```
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
      {
          @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick()
        {
            Log.d("LOGIN::", "Clicked");
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }, "login");
```

to this

```
Button btnLogin=new Button(ctx);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

browser.addJavascriptInterface(btnLogin,"login");

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        //do Something

}
```

and in index.html

```
<html>  <head>  <script language="javascript">  function js1() {
    document.loginform.method="post";  document.loginform.action = "https://example.com/chechlogin.asp";
           }
     </script>  </head>  <body>    <form name="loginform">
     <input type="text" name="empcode" value="58686" /><br/>
     <input type="password" name="emppassNTL" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_id" onclick="btnLogin.performClick();" />
```